# What's an efficient method for querying spatial multiple-file parquet with a geometry in python using DuckDB?

Tags: python, pyarrow, duckdb

The goal is to query nwi given an area of interest.  NWI is stored in parquet file format by state and I'm doing the work with duckdb.

I want to query only the non-Riverine nwi features that overlap with a single aoi the size of a single huc12.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE wetlands as
SELECT ATTRIBUTE, ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromWKB(wetlnd.geometry)) as geometry
FROM read_parquet('/nwi/*.parquet') AS wetlnd
INNER JOIN aoi ON 
ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromWKB(wetlnd.geometry), ST_GeomFromWKB(aoi.geometry))
WHERE wetlnd.WETLAND_TYPE != 'Riverine'
```

I have this running but it's taking a very long time.
Following examples provided on https://github.com/giswqs/geog-414/blob/master/book/duckdb/11_data_analysis.ipynb I think this can be done much faster but I'm failing to see how.  Maybe I need to do some preprocessing and store NWI data at the huc4 level or something?

Each nwi state file is > 1GB which I believe is an issue. Just hoping to use public data instead of having to create my own.

Thanks